# Durandal - prevent binding cause issue with compositionComplete of subViews

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, requirejs, durandal, composition

I work in Durandal-project.

At my project, I need to control the binding-time. i.e, I want to prevent the binding, and do it manually when I want.

```
    define(function organizationView(require) {

var organizationDetails = require('views/organization/organizationDetails');

function myVM() {

    var vm = {

        organizationDetails: new organizationDetails(),
        binding: function () { return { applyBindings: false } }

    };



    http.get(myUrl).done(function initLookupList(lookup) {
        try {
            //my code...

            that.binding = function () { return { applyBindings: true }; };
            binder.bind(that, $('#organization')[0], that, that);
        }
        catch (err) {
            global.treatError(err);
        }
    });
    return vm;

}
return myVM;
});
```

HTML side:

```
<div data-bind="compose: { model: organizationDetails, view:'views/organization/organizationDetails.html'}"></div>
```

my problem is: Durandal not arrive to compositionComplete function of the sub view (organizationDetails)!!!

If I not try control bindings-time, i.e. if I cancel the code: "apply-binding=false" frp, the parent view- it works well.

But I must do it...So what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use parent module's compositioncomplete function.

e.g.

in "**shell**" module you are composing "**nav**" view, than you can write binding logic in "**shell**" compositioncomplete function.

Comment: can you give demo-project? this question is relevant to me, too.

Comment: you can check johnpapa's "Hot  Towel SPA" Template architecture.